# Error 404 when trying to display images from custom folder in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, get, http-status-code-404

I have the following shortcode which gets the images of that post (that will be in a folder named as the post's id ) and displays them echoing as many tag images as needed.

```
    session_start();
    $postID = $_SESSION['post_ID'];
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $path = $upload_dir['basedir'].'/'.'gallery/'.$postID;

    if(file_exists($path)) {
        $pathFile = $path.'/*';
        $images = glob($pathFile);
        if(!empty($images)) {
            foreach($images as $image){
                $alt = end(explode('/', $image));
                echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="'.$alt.'" />';
            }
        } else echo 'No hay imágenes.';

    } else echo 'No hay imágenes.';

?>
```

The problem is that the images aren't displayed, i get the followin error in the brower's console `GET https://path-to-theme/wp-content/uploads/gallery/1658/wwg.jpg 404`, per every image and i get this icon:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5ecd.gif)

I have no idea why my images aren't displayed the images, the path is correct, the images are there, complitely no idea what I'm missing. It's not a permissions problem as i tried giving 755 permissions to the directories starting from  /uploads/.. and so on including the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem. The issue wa sthat i wasn't uploading the images as wp wants me to, therefore the images, even they were in the folder, couldn't be displayed. So I had to change the way i uploaded them, by using wp functions and specifying the mime_type etc so wp could store their metadata in it's db in order to be able to acknowledge them and display them in a future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the URL you reference in your question is actually `https://yourdomain/wp-content/uploads/gallery/1658/wwg.jpg` and not `https://path-to-theme/wp-content/uploads/gallery/1658/wwg.jpg`.  Right?

If that's the case, then it should be able to pull open that file.  The first thing I'd check is whether you actually have the file located where you think it is: `/wp-content/uploads/gallery/1658/`

If the file is actually in that folder, and you can access it from your browser at `https://yourdomain/wp-content/uploads/gallery/1658/wwg.jpg` then my next suggestion would be to check the permission of each of the folders leading up to the file and make sure they are set to 755, and then make sure your file is set to 644.

[Here are instructions on changing file permissions.](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-fix-file-and-folder-permissions-error-in-wordpress/)

Let me know if that helps?

Comment: By " access it from your browser" you mean to put that url in the browser righ? I've tried that but I get the 404 page  does that mean that it does not exist that path? Is a bit confiusing becouse in the ftp program i can see all folders and images were should be.

Comment: Yes sorry the url is ```https://yourdomain/wp-content/uploads/gallery/1658/wwg.jpg```, and yes, i tried with the permissions u told me but the problem remains.

Comment: One simple trick that I try to get closer to the solution is to `print` or `echo` ([instructions](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_echo_print.asp)) the variables onto a page, just so you can make sure that they are actually populating and that they are pointing to what you want them to.

Sometimes the `$path` could be off because the `basedir` is actually pulling in something different hat you desire.  Go ahead and print those to your page and let me know what you find.